# How mature is App Engine Flexible?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

Do you know if there's a more or less certain date for the GA (General Availability) of App Engine Flexible? What would be the worst-case-scenario of driving our production on App Engine Flexible right now? What kind of failures are more likely than others?

Answer (score 2):

NEXT 2017 update ([source](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/03/your-favorite-languages-now-on-Google-App-Engine.html)):

App engine flexible is now GA for Node.js, Ruby, Java 8, Python 2.7 or 3.5, and Go 1.8.

PHP 5.6/7.0/7.1 and ASP.NET are released but are in beta.

You can also bring your own environment with a docker file (or customize the above)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question a few months ago when we started using AppEngine flex. I have asked the GCP team a few times and the latest answer I got was :Q1 2017.

That being said, we've been using them for the past 2.5 months and the services were working just fine.

The AppEngine team is very responsive in answering questions and supporting, which is great.